# Running wom.sh in Terminal, but Error message Appears

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I followed the instructions at the World of Minecraft Website. When I enter the command line in terminal `/home/apotter96/Downloads/wom/wom.sh` it finds it but the Terminal comes back with `Error: Unable to access jarfile lib/boot.jar`. The `boot.jar` is in the lib folder. All I want to do is use my WoM and play Minecraft.

Also, I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Are you *definitely* sure you've got permission to access the `boot.jar`? If not, you might want to either claim the permission for the whole minecraft folder for yourself, or run the shell script as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it can't find it because you're running it from the wrong folder. Command line scripts look for their files based on *your* current directory, not where the script is. `cd` into the folder where `wom.sh` is, then run it directly. If you have to type in the whole path, then you're not in the right directory.

i.e., do this:

```
cd /home/apotter96/Downloads/wom
wom.sh
```